# Error executing action `install` on resource 'newrelic_agent_infrastructure[Install]' using data bag

Tags: linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe, databags

We're trying to install New Relic infrastructure agent using a third party cookbook. But we've got an error:
            Error executing action `install` on resource 'newrelic_agent_infrastructure[Install]'

Our Recipe:

```
#
# Cookbook:: third-party-newrelic
# Recipe:: infraestructure-agent
#
# Copyright:: 2018, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.

include_recipe 'base::databag'
include_recipe 'newrelic::infrastructure_agent'
# Default Variables
newrelic = decrypt_databag('newrelic')

node.normal['newrelic']['license'] = newrelic['license_key']
```

Log Error:

```
Recipe: newrelic::infrastructure_agent
  * newrelic_agent_infrastructure[Install] action install

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `install` on resource 'newrelic_agent_infrastructure[Install]'
    ================================================================================

    RuntimeError
    ------------
    The NewRelic key is required.

    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/newrelic/libraries/helpers.rb:15:in `check_license'
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/newrelic/providers/agent_infrastructure.rb:18:in `block in class_from_file'

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/newrelic/recipes/infrastructure_agent.rb

      8: newrelic_agent_infrastructure 'Install'

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/newrelic/recipes/infrastructure_agent.rb:8:in `from_file'

    newrelic_agent_infrastructure("Install") do
      action [:install]
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :newrelic_agent_infrastructure
      cookbook_name "newrelic"
      recipe_name "infrastructure_agent"
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=13.8.5
    platform=ubuntu
    platform_version=16.04
    ruby=ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=101819;start=19:52:27;
    executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2018-05-10T19:52:34+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2018-05-10T19:52:34+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 07 seconds
[2018-05-10T19:52:34+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2018-05-10T19:52:34+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2018-05-10T19:52:34+00:00] ERROR: newrelic_agent_infrastructure[Install] (newrelic::infrastructure_agent line 8) had an error: RuntimeError: The NewRelic key is required.
[2018-05-10T19:52:34+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Even though using the follow line instead of a data bag:

node.default_unless['newrelic']['license'] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

We've tried many alternatives for this command, but it wasn't fertile.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the relevant code so that should work, but you can try:

```
node.override['newrelic']['application_monitoring']['license'] = 'asdf'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the attribute in a place before it would get used?

Comment: Oh hey, yep, bug in the cookbook https://github.com/djoos-cookbooks/newrelic/blob/master/resources/agent_infrastructure.rb#L11

Comment: It doesn't have the `lazy{}` wrapper so that's getting evaluated at file compile time. You would have to set the attr via a role or environment or something else static.

Comment: Thanks a lot @coderanger, I saw that you have opened an Issue for djoos to correct the wrapper.

". You would have to set the attr via a role or environment or something else static."

We thought about it, but how can we manager to insert a data bag in a role?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You unfortunately cannot use a data bag at this time.

Answer (score 0):

by the issue:
https://github.com/djoos-cookbooks/newrelic/issues/345

Ok. We manage to solve this problem by changing this line in the followed files: 
../resources/agent_infrastructure.rb 
../resources/agent_php.rb

From:

attribute :license, :kind_of => String,  :default => NewRelic.application_monitoring_license(node)

To:

attribute :license, :kind_of => String, :default => lazy { NewRelic.application_monitoring_license(node) }

Inside the recipe

node.default['newrelic']['license'] = newrelic['license_key']

Calling our data bag with this structure:

id:          newrelic

license_key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Thanks for your help.